# Making callouts to webhooks from action skills

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am currently making a Watson Assistant in which I need to store data collected in a database. I am trying to do this by calling an endpoint I have created that will insert data into my database, however I do not know how I can use webhooks in my action skills.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation has an overview of where and how webhooks are supported by Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-webhook-overview). Action skills only offer pre / post message hooks. When you [compare an Action skill with a Dialog skill](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-skills-choose), Action skills are simpler to get started with, but Dialog skills offer all the features. What you are looking for is available for dialog nodes in Dialog skills.

Answer (score 0):

Actions Skill is still quite new compared to Dialog Skill, and we have a lot of really exciting plans for Actions that will be coming out over time. The ability to call out to external systems is being totally revamped, at least compared to Dialog/webhooks, to be much easier to use and scale across your business. It's one of our top priorities for the future but will take some time to release. I can't give a date now but if you need this for your production assistant, as data_henrik said we recommend you use the Dialog skill

Comment: Actually, we're actively looking for sponsor users for what we are considering. Would love to get your feedback as you sound like an experienced user. Feel free to email me at mmason@us.ibm.com if you want to see what we're planning and provide any feedback.